# Cannot upload .mpg file to SP2013 Asset Library

Tags: video, sharepoint-library, asset-library

I have a **standard Asset Library** and **want to upload a .mpg file**, but when I choose the file I get an alert

> "Sorry, format of this video is not supported".

I checked, is available this format in IIS - yes, the feature Rich Media Content is activated. Also I found that .mpg is supported by Media Web Part SP 2013.

Is it mean that it is supported by Asset Library or not?

What cause of this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file type may be blocked by your administrator. If you have administrative rights then you can enable it from Central Administration.

This are called as **Blocked File Types**

For this you can follow following steps :

- Open **Central Administration**
- Click **Security** tab
- In **General Security** click **Define blocked file types**
- On the **Blocked File Types** page, if you want to change the selected web application, on the **Web Application** menu, click **Change Web Application**. Use the **Select Web Application** page to select a web application.
- To stop blocking a file type, select a file type from the list, press the Delete key, and then click OK.

For more information you can click [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc262496.aspx)

If you need to know all the file types which are blocked then you can go [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3?CorrelationId=334ea740-6b47-46c0-874f-02c0586a1bf5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i found that i can't upload any video files except .mp4. Blocked File Types doesn't contains these formats